# VSSOP-8 Package Footprint

Tags: pcb-design, footprint

I am trying to create a footprint for a [LMR61428](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr61428.pdf) but the datasheet (linked) only has the package outline and nothing for the recommended land pattern, or footp for a PCB design.

I found [this image](http://e2e.ti.com/support/power_management/linear_regulators/f/321/p/305954/1069118) on TI after a fair amount of searching for a VSSOP-8 package which is what the LMR61428 claims to be but I am not 100% confident this is actually the correct one - the pitch of the pins are correct but I am not sure about the overall sizes that it gives.

It seems that it *should* work, but I just wanted some clarification before it gets further down the line in my design!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to Sanjeev's point, below comparison indicates that Land pattern can be shared. If still in doubt, ask [TI](https://e2e.ti.com/).

[image]
below is Land Pattern of OPA4170.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not you refer the below datasheet

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa4170.pdf

Page 22-23

Answer (score 1):

Pay careful attention to the device's specification sheet. Land layouts for VSSOP-8 is NOT a one size fits all. Under TI VSSOP-8 I found at least two different package widths. The pcb pad layout dimensions and ic package dimensions are towards the end of the TI datasheets that I have seen. Use the one for the device and figure some way to keep them clearly denoted in your CAD libraries to avoid getting bitten with "throwing stars" for pcbs.